# If $\operatorname{Spec} A＝\operatorname{Spec} B$, then $A$ is isomorphic to $B$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, affine-schemes

[Proposition II.$3.2$ in Hartshorne](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/770418/proposition-ii-3-2-in-hartshorne)
Regarding to this question,
I wonder why $\operatorname{Spec} A＝\operatorname{Spec}  B$, then $A$ is isomorphic to $B$.

To be more precise,

---

> Let $A,B$ are rings, and suppose the schemes $\operatorname{Spec} A$ and $\operatorname{Spec} B$ are
> isomorphic as schemes. Then, I want to show $A$ and $B$ are isomorphic as
> rings.

---

Of course, if we see $\operatorname{Spec} A$ and $\operatorname{Spec} B$ as just a set of prime ideals, then
we cannot say $A$ and $B$ are isomorphic as rings. For example, a pair of another fields is an example.
Thank you.

Comment: Check their global section? (Check II 2.2)

Comment: Please use \operatorname{Spec} to format $\operatorname{Spec}$ - it produces the correct spacing. I've made this fix for you in this post.

Comment: @KReiser, I set up a macro for $\operatorname{Spec}$, for convenience. I hope it is helpful.

Comment: @Aurelio I am one of the two edit reviewers who rejected your edit suggestion. I think setting up a macro is unnecessary in this situation (this is a short post, and not much editing would be expected anyway).

Comment: @ArcticChar, many thanks for explaining that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would avoid saying that things are "equal", but rather that they are isomorphic via a named isomorphism $\newcommand{\Spec}{\operatorname{Spec}}\phi\colon\Spec A\to\Spec B$. If you consider the corresponding map on structure sheaves, and take global sections, you get the morphism $\phi^\#\colon B \to A$. By assumption, $\phi$ has a bilateral inverse, which yields a bilateral inverse to $\phi^\#$.

Regarding your example concerning the spectra of two fields, it is misleading probably because you use a statement of the form "$\Spec k= \Spec k'$", parsing it as an *equality of sets*. If you instead say that $\Spec k \stackrel{\sim}\to \Spec k'$, via a *scheme morphism* $(\phi,\phi^\#)$ which admits an inverse, then your issue is resolved.

**Motto**: «Equality evil, isomorphism good».